# Calculation of cardinality constrained minimum weight matchings

Tags: perfect-matchings, heuristics

Given a complete weighted graph $G(V,E),\ |V|=2n$, calculating a minimum weight matching with $n-k$ edges can be reduced to calculating a perfect matching in $H(V+U,E+F),\ |U|=2k,\ F=(u\in U,v\in V),\ |f|=\text{c}\,\forall f\in F$

> **Question:**
>
> is the minimum weight matching of $G$ with $n-k$ edges the same as the minimum weight perfect matching of $G$ with its $k$ longest edges removed?
>
> If not, what are counter examples for complete graphs?

Comment: This can’t be true, since for $k=n-1$ it implies the minimum weight perfect matching always contains the graph’s shortest edge, which is false.

Comment: @Alf good argument; shame on me that I overlooked it.